# Polymorphism in JSON, Jersey and Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jersey, jackson

Does Jackson with Jersey support polymorphic classes over JSON?

Let's say, for instance, that I've got a Parent class and a Child class that inherits from it. And, let's say I want to use JSON to send & receive both Parent and Child over HTTP.

```
public class Parent {
...
}

public class Child extends Parent {
...
}
```

I've thought about this kind of implementation:

```
@Consumes({ "application/json" }) // This method supposed to get a parent, enhance it and return it back
    public @ResponseBody 
    Parent enhance(@RequestBody Parent parent) {
    ...
    }
```

Question: If I give this function (through JSON of course) a Child object, will it work? Will the Child's extra member fields be serialized, as well ?
Basically, I want to know if these frameworks support polymorphic consume & respond.

BTW, I'm working with Spring MVC.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jackson does support polymorphism,

In your child class annotate with a name:

```
 @JsonTypeName("Child_Class")
 @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "objectType")
 public class Child extends Parent{
 ....
 }
```

In parent you specify sub types:

```
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child.class), @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SomeOther.class)}) 
public class Parent {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Great answer Usman. However, you probably want the @JsonTypeInfo on the parent instead of on the children.

Comment: We could do it that way too, in which case we would have to put name in the JsonSubTypes annotation something like the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798394/polymorphism-in-jackson-annotations-jsontypeinfo-usage

Comment: Jersey 2 uses Jackson 2.X.X which has both of these annotations so I don't see why it would not work. (See http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeName.html)

Comment: What if Parent is a third party interface and you cannot annotate it with JsonSubTypes ? Also adding the type to the Json (via JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS) is not a valid solution because the client should not be changed.

Comment: That is not a good answer, because Jackson will add additional information in the json text, and the text added depends of JAVA, and your class.