# Using polymorphism at deserialization time with Jackson (and MrBean)

Tags: java, json, polymorphism, jackson, deserialization

I'm using Jackson to deserialize some JSON into Java POJOs.  I register the MrBean module with my object mapper, so all I have to do is define a bunch of interfaces, and the POJOs are generated automagically, based on those interfaces.

I would like to have a Credentials interface with various types of credentials that extend it, e.g. UsernamePasswordCredentials and CertificateFileCredentials.

Doing this without any annotations or other incantations to try to make it work gives me the following error in my unit test:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "username" (Class org.codehaus.jackson.generated.SCRUBBED.Credentials), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@e0b6f5; line: 32, column: 29] (through reference chain: HostConfiguration["hostDefinitions"]->HostDefinition["credentials"]->Credentials["username"])
```

I've also [followed the instructions at another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565299/polymorphism-in-json-jersey-and-jackson), and I'm getting the same error.

The error makes sense; Jackson is trying to map the contents of my JSON file to an empty interface.  However, I (naively, perhaps) expected Jackson to look for interfaces that extend the base Credentials interface and try to match up the fields in those interfaces to the fields it found in the JSON object.

I've seen some examples at the Jackson wiki that make use of meta-information in the JSON object, e.g. decorating an object with `"@class":"foo.bar.CertificateFileCredentials"`, but I'd prefer to avoid any of that since my JSON input will be generated automatically by other services, and those other services shouldn't have to know anything about the internals of my service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How would you define actual implementation classes? As additional interfaces? Those should get generated correctly; but the problem is during deserialization: there must be some way for deserializer to find out actual type to use, if there are multiple choices.
For this, `@JsonTypeInfo` is recommended to be used as you have noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the technique would work well for your purposes too, even though you don't control the service that generates the JSON.

Saving the class name is a nice easy default when using @JsonTypeInfo but Jackson lets you customize this to your liking.

For example, suppose the service generates JSON that looks like this:

```
{   meows: 400, furColor: "green",   species: "cat"   }
```

Then you can define these interfaces to convert it properly.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,property="species")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Feline.class, name="cat")
})
public interface Animal {
    public String getFurColor();
}

@JsonTypeName("cat")
public interface Feline extends Animal {
    @JsonProperty("meows") // just to have an example of a renamed property...
    public long getMeowingVolumeInDecibels();
}
```

Then you should just automatically get the right java type at runtime when deserializing, as well as automatically generate the "species" property depending on the runtime type. Hope that helps!