# Polymorphism in jackson annotations: @JsonTypeInfo usage

Tags: java, polymorphism, jackson, deserialization

I would like to know if `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation can be used for interfaces. I have set of classes which should be serialized and deserialized.

Here is what I'm trying to do. I have two implementation classes `Sub1`, `Sub2` implementing `MyInt`. Some of the model classes have the interface reference for the implementation types. I would like to deserialize the objects based on polymorphism

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(name="sub1", value=Sub1.class), 
    @Type(name="sub2", value=Sub2.class)})
public interface MyInt{
}

@JsonTypeName("sub1")
public Sub1 implements MyInt{
}

@JsonTypeName("sub2")
public Sub2 implements MyInt{
}
```

I get the following `JsonMappingException`:

> Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: need JSON String
>   that contains type id

Comment: you saw this? http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/mapper-not-include-type-information-when-serializing-object-why?xg_source=activity do you have any list without type mentioned like discussed in the other thread?

Comment: I think you need to show bit more code (how serialization, deserialization is done), as well as JSON being produced/consumed.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`@JsonSubTypes.Type` must have a value and a name like this,

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property="type")
@JsonSubTypes({       
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Dog.class, name="dog"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Cat.class, name="cat")       
})
```

In the subclass, use `@JsonTypeName("dog")` to say the name.
The values `dog` and `cat` will be set in the property named `type`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I still get the same error. Do you think I should change anything in @JsonTypeInfo also ?

Comment: Does any one know if JsonTypeInfo can be applied to interfaces at all ?

Comment: Issue could be with your input json string. are you trying to POST something?

Comment: No. I'm just doing a HTTP-GET

Comment: ok, please update your question to include the subclasses also. what are the annotations on your subclasses?

Comment: updated the answer, add property in the @JSONTypeInfo and see if it works, sorry i didnt notice that earlier.

Comment: And yes, @JsonTypeInfo can be used for interfaces, if that helps (annotation handling by Jackson does support inheritance)

Comment: @SenthilKumar Thanks for the info.. I was missing property="type"

Comment: @StaxMan Thanks for the info.. This annotation is applicable to interfaces as well.

Comment: Can I do it without annotations?

Comment: But what if someone else is trying to implement your Interface? You cannot unmarshal a new concrete type named "sub3" to a MyInt without adding the annotation in your Interface file.

Comment: Good explanation and updated examples here: http://www.davismol.net/2015/03/05/jackson-json-deserialize-a-list-of-objects-of-subclasses-of-an-abstract-class/

Comment: This worked for me for Interfaces.. well Appreciated explanation

Answer (score 5):

**Yes it can be used both for abstract classes and interfaces.**

Consider following code example

Suppose we have an enum , interface and classes

```
enum VehicleType {
    CAR,
    PLANE
}

interface Vehicle {
    VehicleType getVehicleType();
    String getName();
}


@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
class Car implements Vehicle {
    private boolean sunRoof;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public VehicleType getVehicleType() {
        return VehicleType.Car;
    }
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
class Plane implements Vehicle {
    private double wingspan;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public VehicleType getVehicleType() {
        return VehicleType.Plane;
    }
}
```

If we try to deserialize this json into `List<Vehicle>`

```
[
  {"sunRoof":false,"name":"Ferrari","vehicleType":"CAR"}, 
  {"wingspan":19.25,"name":"Boeing 750","vehicleType":"PLANE"}
]
```

then we will get error

```
abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```

To solve this just add following `JsonSubTypes` and `JsonTypeInfo` annotations to the interface, as shown below

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "vehicleType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Car.class, name = "CAR"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Plane.class, name = "PLANE")
})
interface Vehicle {
    VehicleType getVehicleType();
    String getName();
}
```

With this the deserialization will work with interface and you will get a `List<Vehicle>` back

You can check out the code here - https://github.com/chatterjeesunit/java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/play/util/jackson/PolymorphicDeserialization.java

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin, it also works without declaring the Subtypes manually. Like this:

```kotlin
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "kind")
sealed class Something {
    val kind = this::class.java.simpleName
}
```

Note you need to seal the class though.