# Jersey Jackson and Spring Service

Tags: spring, rest, jersey, jackson

We are using Jersey, Jackson and Spring service (@service) annotation to expose some REST based Web-Services. Request and response data are exchanged in JSON Format.

Below is the Service Request Object content:

```
public class ServiceRequest{
   private RequestHeader requestHeader;
   private List<BaseEntity> requestData;
}
```

All specific entities will extend from BaseEntity class. For example :

```
public class User extends BaseEntity{
  private String userName;
}
```

For all service operation we accept only ServiceRequest Object by passing list of request data objects. Now when we try to call these operation from REST Client, these are failing with

```
 userName is not found as part of BaseEntity.
```

This is because while converting, Jersey/Jackson tries to autodetect the incoming field names with the specified object's property.

I want to know is there any way, I can handle this in an intelligent way. We do not have an option to change the signature of the Service. Really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: is your BaseEntity a JavaBean ?(ie do you have a getter/setter for userName)

Comment: BaseEntity is a JavaBean. But the User (which has username) extends BaseEntity. BaseEntity just contains id, created by, created Date, update by, updated date (which are common for all entities).

Comment: The below link has the answer for my question. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798394/polymorphism-in-jackson-annotations-jsontypeinfo-usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below link has the answer for my question. Thank you for the support.

[Polymorphism in jackson annotations: @JsonTypeInfo usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798394/polymorphism-in-jackson-annotations-jsontypeinfo-usage)

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried to use generics?  You can declare concrete class type at Resource's to inform Jackson to map to specific type