# Ajax call with Jackson marshaling of subclasses (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a controller that receives an abstract class.
This class has 3 different subclasses.

In order for the controller to receive the ajax call i must add a "@class" : com.my.project.my.Class
parameter to the object i'm sending.

This feels really bad to implement.
Is there any other ways to send the subclasses and avoiding forcing the client to pass an actual class name with each call.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson has its own inheritance handling mechanism. You don't necessarily need to use `@class`. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798394/polymorphism-in-jackson-annotations-jsontypeinfo-usage).

This feature cannot be the cleanest. Jackson does its deserialization through hints from the developer. Notice how you always pass a `Class` or `TypeReference` object when interacting with its `ObjectMapper`. In the same way, the JSON needs to contain hints for which subtype to deserialize to.