# jackson why do I need JsonTypeName annotation on subclasses

Tags: java, json, scala, jackson, jackson-module-scala

At [this link](https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/blob/master/src/main/scala/json/jackson/SubClasses.scala)

I'm trying to understand **why** do I (may) need `@JsonTypeName` on subclasses (like all 'internet; [sujests to put](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798394/polymorphism-in-jackson-annotations-jsontypeinfo-usage)) if it works without it **?**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "aType")
@JsonSubTypes(Array(
  new Type(value = classOf[ModelA], name = "ModelA"),
  new Type(value = classOf[ModelB], name = "ModelB")
))
class BaseModel(val modelName:String)

//@JsonTypeName("SomeModel")  // Commented. Do I need this?
class ModelA(val a:String, val b:String, val c:String, commonData:String)  extends BaseModel(commonData) {
  def this() = this("default", "default", "default" ,"default")
}
//@JsonTypeName("SomeModel") // Commented. Do I need this?
class ModelB(val a:String, val b:String, val c:String, commonData:String)  extends BaseModel(commonData) {
  def this() = this("default", "default", "default" ,"default")
}
```

Comment: Does it work without them? I.e. can you deserialize json with `"aType":"ModelB"` into the correct objects? There is lots of cargo cult programming, some may have been required once upon a time

Comment: yest.that works "to and from". i guess it may be needed. just want to know at wich case. i guess it may depends on JsonTypeInfo params other than Id.Name.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need them.

The [documentation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSubTypes.Type.html) of `@JsonSubTypes.Type` explains

> Definition of a subtype, along with optional name. If name is missing, class of the type will be checked for JsonTypeName annotation; and if that is also missing or empty, a default name will be constructed by type id mechanism. Default name is usually based on class name.

You should have either

```
@JsonSubTypes(Array(
  new Type(value = classOf[ModelA], name = "ModelA")

... 

class ModelA
```

or

```
@JsonSubTypes(Array(
  new Type(value = classOf[ModelA])

... 

@JsonTypeName("ModelA")
class ModelA
```