# Add SubType information at runtime using Jackson for polymorphism

Tags: java, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization, unmarshalling

I am using Jackson to unmarshal polymorphic types from JSON. I am using the `@JsonTypeInfo`, `@JsonSubTypes`, and `@JsonTypeName` annotations similar to Example 4 in [this post](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html). My question is, say now I need someone else to extend my code and add a 3rd class: `public class Duck extends Animal` outside of the original code base. How can I (or the others) add the SubType information without modifying the source code (annotation) of the `public abstract Animal class`?

UPDATE:

I am forced to use @JsonTypeName to solve the POJO version changes. For example:

```
package my.zoo;
@JsonTypeInfo(  
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
    property = "type")  
@JsonSubTypes({  
    @Type(value = Cat.class, name = "my.zoo.cat@1.0"),  
    @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "my.zoo.dog@1.0"),
    @Type(value = Catv2.class, name = "my.zoo.cat@2.0")})
public abstract class Animal {
    ...
}

@JsonTypeName("my.zoo.cat@1.0")
public class Cat extends Animal {
    ...
}

@JsonTypeName("my.zoo.cat@2.0")
public class Catv2 extends Animal {
    ...
}

@JsonTypeName("my.zoo.dog@1.0")
public class Dog extends Animal {
    ...
}

// in another java package/project
package another.zoo;
import my.zoo.*;

@JsonTypeName("my.zoo.dog@2.0")
public class Dogv2 extends Animal {
    ...
}
```

Now the problem I am facing is that I cannot unmarshal a JSON that has type name "my.zoo.dog@2.0" without adding `@Type(value = another.zoo.Dogv2.class, name = "my.zoo.Dog@2.0")})` to the `Animal` class. So doing this with annotation is obviously not possible. Is there a way to do this at runtime?

UPDATE 2:

I just found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798394/polymorphism-in-jackson-annotations-jsontypeinfo-usage?rq=1) with the same/similar use case. My concern here is that using annotation will prevent people from extending/implementing your base class/interface. I would like a way to still keep extensibility of my base class/interface and make sure my (un)marshalling logic will work with future concrete types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up using Reflections library to find all subtype of `Animal` class, and register JsonSubTypes with `mapper.registerSubtypes(Class<?>... classes)` method.

Comment: What did you do with the @JsonTypeInfo annotation? Did you use JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME?

Comment: @ampofila, the model code is as shown in the sample code. The. RegisterSubtypes() calls were made in the application driver during bootstrap. Jackson would take care of everything when deserializing the json.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. However I am not sure how to intercept a REST service (I have a controller that takes as param the interface and automatically unmarhsalls the inbound json). Your way works when I read something from a file but it does not suit a POST request using REST.

Comment: @ampofila, sorry but I have no experience in that.

Comment: @derrdji Can you provide an example on how you have used `mapper.registerSubtypes`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `@JsonSubTypes`. Use [`@JsonTypeInfo#use`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html#use%28%29) with [`JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.Id.html#CLASS) to identify types for serialization and deserialization.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
abstract class Animal { /* whatever */ }
```

Jackson will then store the fully qualified name to serialize the object and use it again to determine a target class for deserialization.

You'll have to make sure none of the subclasses have a property named `type`.

---

It's possible to make this work with `@JsonSubTypes` but it involves mixins and is not a very maintainable solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! However, I am forced to use @JsonTypeName("") annotation like in the updated example. Is there a way to work with that?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  Yes, but this way you still have to pass the full class name in the json text (ie. {"type" : "my.class", "data" : { ... }}). Right?

Comment: @ampofila In this setup, yes. There's [`JsonTypeInfo.Id.Custom`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.Id.html#CUSTOM) for more options.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I will take a look at it.

Comment: You could use capital letters in the type property name, such as "TYPE", to ensure that no class overrides this property with another one, at least if it sticks with the Java naming conventions.

Comment: is there a way to add  validation on type ??.