# Alternative to Jackson mixins for a variable number of subtypes?

Tags: java, json, jackson, mixins

I am writing a library, intended to be used by other apps, containing a bunch of classes that implement the same interface, like in this example:

```java
public interface Figure {
  // ...
}

public class Triangle implements Figure {
  // ...
}

public class Square implements Figure {
  // ...
}

public class Circle implements Figure {
  // ...
}
```

And then I have a mixin for all the classes above:

```java
  @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
  @JsonSubTypes({
      @JsonSubTypes.Type(Triangle.class),
      @JsonSubTypes.Type(Square.class),
      @JsonSubTypes.Type(Circle.class)
  })
  public interface FigureMixin {

  }
```

I can add this mixin to the `ObjectMapper` as usual:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(Figure.class, FigureMixin.class);
```

The problem is that users of the library might want to provide their own classes that implement `Figure`. Therefore, the annotation approach is not suitable, because I don't know at compile time how many JSON subtypes (i.e. classes implementing `Figure`) there will be.

Is there any way to register the subtypes at runtime for all available classes implementing the common interface, i.e. achieve the same mixin configuration but without using annotations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look of [objectMapper.registerSubtypes()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#registerSubtypes(java.lang.Class...))

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34079050/14032355

Comment: Thanks @ikhvjs, that related question helped me to find the answer I needed, which I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [the example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079050/add-subtype-information-at-runtime-using-jackson-for-polymorphism), I was able to achieve the desired behavior:

First, use `@JsonTypeInfo` in the interface implemented by all my classes:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
public interface Figure {
  // ...
}
```

Then, register all my classes as subtypes into the ObjectMapper:

```java
public void configure(final ObjectMapper mapper) {
  mapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(Triangle.class));
  mapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(Square.class));
  mapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(Circle.class));
}
```

Of course the calls to `registerSubtypes(...)` can be placed in different methods if needed.