# Jackson polymorphic behaviour with abstract class

Tags: java, jackson, polymorphism

Having a class `DocumentMapping` that contains various fields. One of those fields is a class `BinaryDocumentMapping` which is abstract. `BinaryDocumentMapping` is extended by 3 other classes `ExcelDocumentMapping`, `XMLDocumentMapping` and `CSVDocumentMapping`.

So I'm having :

```
public class DocumentMapping{

    @JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ExcelDocumentMapping.class, name = "EXCEL"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CsvDocumentMapping.class, name = "CSV"), @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = XmlDocumentMapping.class, name = "XML") })
    private BinaryDocumentMapping binary = null;
```

where

```
public abstract class BinaryDocumentMapping
    implements Serializable {
```

and

```
@JsonTypeName("CSV")
public class CsvDocumentMapping
```

The serialization works ok but I have problem when reading the json into an object:

```
mapper.reader().withType(DocumentMapping.class).readValue(jsonData);
```

which throws

> `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException`: Can not construct
>   instance of `com.documentmapping.BinaryDocumentMapping`, problem:
>   abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom
>   deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information

Is there any way to deserialize into the concrete class based on the type ?

Comment: you need to specify @JsonTypeInfo (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11798485/1976843)

Comment: Correct, @JEY. Thanks ! Please post as answer so I can close.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify [@JsonTypeInfo](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JsonTypeInfo) look at [stackoverflow.com/a/11798485/1976843](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11798485/1976843)