# Jackson polymorphism: Deserializing based on a condition

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize below json

```
{ "id" : "1",
  "vehicles" : [
     {"brand":"ferrari", "make":"2016"},
     {"brand":"mclaren", "make":"2011"},
     {"brand":"honda", "make":"2015"}, 
     {"brand":"volkswagen", "make":"2014"} 
  ]
}
```

I have two classes SuperCar.java and NormalCar.java

I want to deserialize above json in such a way that ferrari and mclaren objects are deserialized as SuperCar.java
and honda and volkswagen as NormalCar.java

The deserialization is based on the field 'brand', but as you can see it is not straight forward.
If brand is in the list `{"mclaren", "ferrari", "bugatti", "lamborgini"}` then the vehicle should be deserialized as `SuperCar.java`.

Similarly if brand is in the list `{"honda", "hyundai", "nissan"}` then it should be deserialized as `NormalCar.java`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: why don't you simply deserialize first and then apply condition to separate the list as you want -based on your `brand` field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63283743/2308683